# POSTGRES: pg_cancel_backend does not always work (reason behind it)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I'm currenty using postgres as my database engine, which i've hooked up to a web application.

I'm have noticed on some occasions that there are locks that get accumlated in the database, mainly AccessSharedLocks (when running the query: select * from pg_locks).

One thing I have noticed is that to cancel a process that is acquiring a lock you can use pg_cancel_backend(pid), but sometime i realise that this doesnt always work!! And i'm curious to know why. Is it that this function sends a SIGINT to the database to shut it down gracefully? meaning that it wont shut it down immediately?

There is pg_terminate_backend, but i prefer to not use this.

Any advice on why pg_cancel_backend intermittently works (or at least some explanation) would be grateful).

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`pg_cancel_backend` and `pg_terminate_backend` send signals to the process.

The backend checks ever so often for pending interrupts, but it can happen that execution is in a place where it takes a while until that happens.

Canceling a query won't get rid of the locks until the transaction is closed.

Comment: ok thanks. so when you mean it won't get rid of the locks until the transaction is closed, do you mean until the transaction is finished? Also if i didn't want to wait for the transaction to be closed would the pg_terminate_backend function be the alternative?

Comment: `pg_terminate_backend` will close the transaction. Yes, I was talking about finishing the transaction.